# Ffmpeg linking problems using CMake

Tags: c++, linux, linker, ffmpeg, cmake

I'm writing an application containig 2 internal libraries and depends on more 2 external libraries (ffmpeg and opencv). I'm also using CMake to produce UNIX makefiles. And the problem is when i'm trying to build sources, it compiles but don't link with ffmpeg at all and the next output the linker gives:

```
../../Decoder/libDecoder.a(ConverterAVFrameToRGB.cpp.o): In function `FaceVideo::ConverterAVFrameToRGB::to_rgb_conversion(std::vector<AVFrame*, std::allocator<AVFrame*> >&, int, int, int)':
ConverterAVFrameToRGB.cpp:(.text+0x990): undefined reference to `av_frame_free'
../../Decoder/libDecoder.a(FfmpegDecoder.cpp.o): In function `FaceVideo::FfmpegDecoder::destroy()':
FfmpegDecoder.cpp:(.text+0xa30): undefined reference to `av_frame_free'
../../Decoder/libDecoder.a(FfmpegDecoder.cpp.o): In function `FaceVideo::FfmpegDecoder::decode_next_chunk(int)':
FfmpegDecoder.cpp:(.text+0xb6b): undefined reference to `av_frame_clone'
FfmpegDecoder.cpp:(.text+0xc13): undefined reference to `av_frame_free'
../../Decoder/libDecoder.a(FfmpegEncoder.cpp.o): In function `FaceVideo::FfmpegEncoder::destroy()':
FfmpegEncoder.cpp:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `avcodec_free_frame'
../../Decoder/libDecoder.a(FfmpegEncoder.cpp.o): In function `FaceVideo::FfmpegEncoder::encode()':
FfmpegEncoder.cpp:(.text+0x4c4): undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video2'
FfmpegEncoder.cpp:(.text+0x592): undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video2'
../../Decoder/libDecoder.a(FrameSaver.cpp.o): In function `FaceVideo::FrameSaver::saver(std::vector<AVFrame*, std::allocator<AVFrame*> >&, int, int, int)':
FrameSaver.cpp:(.text+0x869): undefined reference to `av_frame_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

That's excatly what i don't want to see.

There are three Cmake files: two for internal libraries (use

```
add_library(Decoder ${SOURCES_DECODER})
             and 
add_library(Detector ${SOURCES_DETECTOR})
```

in them) and one for main executable (use

```
add_executable(Tool ${SOURCES_TOOL})
             and
target_link_libraries (Tool Decoder avutil avcodec swscale avformat Detector ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

in it).

As far as i understand from CMake manuals and examples, this should make linker link this libraries together, but no effect.

I've been trying lot of things such as:
1) Adding `link_directories()` with path to libraries (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ for me) wherever it's possile, nothing changed.
2) Linking every library separately, i mean i tried do something like this in my internal libraries CMake files: `target_link_libraries (Decoder avutil avcodec swscale avformat)`. And then link library together into my Tool CMake file: `target_link_libraries (Tool Decoder Detector)`.
3) Editing output makefiles.
4) Compiling simple one-file application just to test whether i can do it or not. I can. `g++ -lavcodec -o out mysource.cpp` works perfectly.
5) Compling ffmpeg manually and installing it.

The fact is i realy don't know what should i do. I have no idea. And i would very appreciate your every answer.

**UPD1:**
Output when CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE is set

> !
>   /usr/bin/c++    -march=x86-64 -Wall -fPIC -pthread -std=c++0x -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS     -march=x86-64  -fPIC  CMakeFiles/FaceDetectorTool.dir/home/anton/Programming/facevideo/branches/Stream_Prototype/src/tools/FaceDetectorTool/facedetector.cpp.o  -o FaceDetectorTool -rdynamic ../../Detector/libDetector.a ../../Decoder/libDecoder.a -lavutil -lavcodec -lswscale -lavformat /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.7 -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.7 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.7 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib

**UPD2**
Cmake example looks like that.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (Decoder)
include(../CMakeInit.cmake)
include_directories(${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${Stream_Facevideo_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/kernel/decoder/)
include_directories(${Stream_Facevideo_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/kernel/stuff/)
set(SOURCES_VIDEODECODER
            *sources*
  )

if(WINDOWS)
    set(SOURCES_VIDEODECODER    ${SOURCES_VIDEODECODER} 
            *headers*                           
    )
endif(WINDOWS)

set (SOURCES_DECODER
    ${SOURCES_VIDEODECODER}
)

add_library(Decoder ${SOURCES_DECODER})
link_directories("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")
target_link_libraries(Decoder swscale avformat avcodec avutil)
```

Comment: Can you give us the code, too?

Comment: @arc_lupus: Sorry, do you wnat application or CMake code? There are lot sources in application and the main fact - it builts on Windows. So i think that is all OK with them. I can post some CMake files you want.

Comment: Please try setting CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE to true, and post the command line for the faulty linking.

Comment: @SirDarius: Well, done!

Comment: If the FFmpeg libs are really dependencies of `Decoder`, you should link them there.  CMake will then always link them to any other target which depends on `Decoder`.  (Same goes for `Detector` if applicable).  That doesn't fix your problem though.  I think this may be an issue related to the order of the FFmpeg libs.  Can you try adding `target_link_libraries(Decoder avformat avcodec swscale avutil)` in `Decoder`'s CMakeLists.txt, I guess `target_link_libraries(Detector ${OpenCV_LIBS})` in `Detector`'s, and just `target_link_libraries(Tool Decoder Detector)` in the top-level one?

Comment: @Fraser Sure i tried to link them in every possible order. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this solution should work: [Findavutil.cmake](https://github.com/arjanhouben/SDL_ffmpeg/blob/master/Findavutil.cmake) & [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/arjanhouben/SDL_ffmpeg/blob/master/lib/CMakeLists.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like you forget to add [LINK_DIRECTORIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3alink_directories) for ffmpeg lib.

If it's ok then try to change order of linking libs in target_link_libraries for executable or add target_link_libraries for your internal libs, that use external ones.

Comment: AS i wrote i tried adding link_directories() statement wherever it's possible. And changed order of linking libraries in every possible way. Nothing changed. I can post example of my CMake file if you want. Another thing i've noticed is that in ConverterAVFrameToRGB.cpp i uses sws_getContext function before av_frame_free() and it's not listed in linker output. Does it mean that swscale library is linked to executable and avutil - not?

Comment: Did you try target_link_libraries(Decoder ${NEEDED_LIBS}) after add_library(Decoder ${SOURCES_DECODER}) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Well i'll post my cmake code. Is there a way to hide it under a spoiler or somthing else?

Comment: see [Findavutil.cmake](https://github.com/arjanhouben/SDL_ffmpeg/blob/master/Findavutil.cmake) & [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/arjanhouben/SDL_ffmpeg/blob/master/lib/CMakeLists.txt)

Comment: Oh, vok1980! Such a great help! It really works! Thanks a lot! I think there is a sense in posting it like an answer.